# split before first comma in pandas and output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to output the following table in pandas. I only have the `description` column so far but I want to split on the comma and output the contents before the comma in the `commondescrip` column.

I have the description column right now, I need the commondescrip column

| description | commondescrip |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 00001 |
| 00002 | 00002 |
| 00003,Area01 | 00003 |
| 00004 | 00004 |
| 00005,Area02 | 00005 |

I tried

```
splitword = df2["description"].str.split(",", n=1, expand = True)
df2["commondescrip"] = splitword[0]
```

but it gives me NaN for those rows that have Area.

How can I fix it so that I can achieve the above the table and split it to output before the comma?

Comment: please provide the expected output for clarity

Comment: @QuangHoang expected output is the table shown. I only have the left column, I need the common description column

Comment: @mozway expected output is the table shown. I only have the left column, I need the common description column

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't split, this would require to handle several parts while you're only interested in one: **remove or extract**.

removing everything after the first comma:

```
df['commondescrip'] = df['description'].str.replace(',.*', '', regex=True)
```

or extracting everything before the first comma:

```
df['commondescrip'] = df['description'].str.extract('([^,]+)')
```

output:

```
    description commondescrip
0         00001         00001
1         00002         00002
2  00003,Area01         00003
3         00004         00004
4  00005,Area02         00005
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
df['description'].apply(lambda x: x.strip().split(',')[0])
```

```
0    00001
1    00002
2    00003
3    00004
4    00005
Name: description, dtype: object
```